# How to convert csv to json by WSO2 ESB Smook

Tags: wso2, smooks, wso2-esb

I need complete two Task; At the first,read CSV file by VFS Transport,convert to JSON, then Call Rest API insert to DB in the end;But I feel puzzled,How to Mapping Data Format

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://www.rajeevs.net/2015/10/wso2-esb-transferring-data-from-files.html) has somewhat similar usecase with some example configurations. (you'll need to modify/extend it to support json and call the rest service)

Comment: Would you mind posting the relevant parts of the blog post here?  Links can sometimes go dead, and without the link this answer really doesn't stand on its own.